# Use value from combo box to determine which field is searched in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to use the value from a combo box to select which field will be searched when the text box is updated.

This code works but only allows for searching on PatientID:

```
Private Sub txtGoTo_AfterUpdate()

If (txtGoTo & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.FindFirst "[PatientID] =" & txtGoTo
If rs.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, no such record '" & txtGoTo & "' was found.", _
           vbOKOnly + vbInformation
Else
    Me.Recordset.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End If
rs.Close
txtGoTo = Null

End Sub
```

This code DOES NOT work but should convey what I am trying to do (changes bold):

```
Private Sub txtGoTo_AfterUpdate()

**GCriteria = cboSearchField.Value & " LIKE '*" & txtSearchString & "*'"**

If (txtGoTo & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.FindFirst "[**Gcriteria**] =" & txtGoTo
If rs.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, no such record '" & txtGoTo & "' was found.", _
           vbOKOnly + vbInformation
Else
    Me.Recordset.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End If
rs.Close
txtGoTo = Null

End Sub
```

Comment: The changes didn't bold properly but the two changes are the gCriteria line at the top and the usage of gCriteria on the rs.FindFirst line

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be just that change from:

```
 rs.FindFirst "[**Gcriteria**] =" & txtGoTo
```

To:

```
 rs.FindFirst Gcriteria
```

As you have already set the condition before:

```
 *GCriteria = cboSearchField.Value & " LIKE '*" & txtSearchString & "*'"**
```